# What's the simplest way to send push notifications to an iOS app using NodeJS?

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need some direction here. Im a budding iOS developer that's dabbling in some NodeJS backend work for a sample project I'm working on. Maybe Im spoiled because of my mobile background, but Im having trouble finding tutorials / finding what the standard is on what's the most efficient way to send push notifications to an iOS app.

For example, after looking online I figured going Firebase/CGM was a good way. But after some more digging, I came up short on how to actually accomplish this. After even more digging, I became overwhelmed at the number of packages that claim to accomplish this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what route I should take and why?

For the record, I ask for the simplest way because I'm looking to prototype an app in a short period of time (rather then dive in and learn everything myself)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `node-apn`. Its a library for sending push notifications to iOS. All you need is Apple Push Key and Certificate.

Read the docs, its pretty simple.